How to store realtime streaming videos to S3? AWS MediaLive MediaPackage -
I'm using AWS MediaLive to push video content in real-time from mobile devices. Then I'm using AWS MediaPackage to digest the input, i.e. the output from AWS MediaLive. With AWS MediaLive I create origin endpoints to let users/viewers watch live streamings.
Now, I don't know how to store the live streaming video to S3 and distribute it through a CDN, in order to let watching the video even once the streaming is ended. Is something provided by AWS out-of-the-box?
